# How to build spark conenctor with different spark streaming interfaces ( spark 3.0.0. 3.1.0 and 3.2.0)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compilation, sbt

I develop spark connector for a custom datasource. In one of our previous releases we realized that internal streaming traits `SupportsStreamingUpdate` from Spark 3.0.0 has been renamed to `SupportsStreamingUpdateAsAppend` in Spark 3.1.0. (and perhaps will happen in the future as well), and were forced to support till spark 3.0.2.
This implies folks can't use the connector with both spark 3.0.0 and spark 3.1.0 simultaneously.

I want to avoid adding a new branch for spark 3.0.0, 3.1.0 and ....
afaik, I can only compile with one spark version at a time. Any suggestions on how I can interface with multiple versions of spark traits in same connector branch.

The build.sbt looks something like this

```
val sparkVer = sysPropOrDefault("version","3.0.3")
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVer % Provided,
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % hadoopVer % Provided,
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % hadoopVer % Provided,
......
```

Please don't hesitate to ask any question If my intent was not clearly stated.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand your need but you could build a version of your connector for each Spark version using for instance SBT build matrix plugin with custom axis.

Comment: @GaëlJ Thanks. seems promising, I'll give it a shot.